# How can you make multiple overlapping markers in Google Maps open their own infowindow when one is clicked

Tags: javascript, events, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps API V3 in javascript.  I have multiple markers that are in a close proximity to each other.  I want to make it so that when a user clicks a marker the infowindow of that marker and any markers overlapping it will open (I need to bubble the event click to all the other markers that overlap the clicked pixel).  I can get the infowindow of the highest z-indexed marker to open, but I need to open the windows of the markers underneath too.  Can this be done, and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

Try OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier

https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier

There is a demo here - http://jawj.github.com/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/demo.html

It attempts to give the same 'clustering' behaviour as the Earth Api.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't do this directly, because the other markers will simply not receive that event, and the clicked marker doesn't know about the others at the same location.

I think the solution would be to use some marker clustering, like [markerclusterer](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html). Then to enhance that library in such a way that each cluster can handle its onclick event and then perform the operations needed on markers it contains. I think markerclusterer currently doesn't support this so you would either have to enhance it (that would be very useful for others if you'd then share it!), or try to look for some library that can do it already (don't know about it)... When you find a solution, please post it here as answer.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I will post an answer if I find one.  For now what I've done is simply put the information about markers that overlap into the same marker (so I get rid of overlapping markers).  This is less than ideal, but for my purposes it is a workaround I can currently live with.

Comment: @Boundless, yes, that's what I would also do :-)