# Placing map markers around another marker to prevent duplicate pin drops

Tags: php, google-maps, math, google-maps-markers

I'm plotting markers for addresses held in a database on a google map using markers.  Unfortunately, some of the businesses in the database share office buildings which means they have the same long/lat for their address/postcode which means that you only see one marker but what I need to show is each marker offset a little from the original as each business is a different business not all the same one in the same building - eg Osaka Fish Concern, Quahog Toys, Widgets ltd etc.

I can't believe how much maths i've forgotten over the years and can't figure out the right term to search for the equation.

What I need is a simple equation to place a marker in a circular pattern around another point.

For example, if I receive data with 10 businesses which all have the same long/lat, the first will get plotted at the exact long/lat but the other 9 i'd like to plot close by but ideally looking like they're in a circle around the first.

I've implemented a method of doing this that does some randomising of direction for long/lat for now but some of them are ending up too far away to be considered part of the same thing.

The current routine is a very simple case of adding or subtracting a fixed distance from the value and then checking if we've already got that in our list.

I'm pre-processing all the data in the server so the routine is running in PHP.

```
            <?php
    $tmpList = Array();

    $latLngKeys = Array();

    foreach ($officeList as $oItem) {
        if ($oItem['lat'] == null && $oItem['lng'] == null) { continue; }

        // now ensure that we don't get multiple lat/lng at same points
        $latLngOk = false;
        $lat = $oItem['lat'];
        $lng = $oItem['lng'];
        $origLatLng = md5($lat.$lng);
        $displaceLat = 0.0000250000;
        $displaceLng = 0.0000250000;

        while (!$latLngOk) {
            $latLng = md5($lat.$lng);
            if (isset($latLngKeys[$latLng])) {
                //echo "Key: $latLng, Orig lat: $lat, orig lng: $lng\n";
                $numSame = $latLngKeys[$origLatLng];
                //$numSame = 1;
                $dirX = rand(0,1);
                $dirY = rand(0,1);
                if ($dirX == 0) { $dispLat = $displaceLat; } else { $dispLat = -$displaceLat; }
                if ($dirY == 0) { $dispLng = $displaceLng; } else { $dispLng = -$displaceLng; }                 
                $lat = $oItem['lat'] + ($dispLat * $numSame);
                $lng = $oItem['lng'] + ($dispLng * $numSame);
                //echo "numSame: $numSame, dirX: $dirX, diry: $dirY, dispLat: $dispLat, dispLng: $dispLng, lat: $lat, lng: $lng, key: $latLng\n"; flush();
                $latLngKeys[$latLng]++;                 
            } else {
                $latLngKeys[$origLatLng]++;
                $latLngOk = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        $oItem['lat'] = $lat;
        $oItem['lng'] = $lng;
        $tmpList[] = $oItem;
    }

            ?>
```

This does actually work and keeps them reasonably tight, i'd just like to perfect it a little.

Thanks.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but why not simply collapse all of the markers within a small enough area into a single marker, give it a different icon to denote there is more than one business, then display the list in the mouseover/popup/etc?

Comment: See this similar question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205336/how-can-you-make-multiple-overlapping-markers-in-google-maps-open-their-own-info

Comment: Client requirement sadly, thought about doing that this afternoon when they pointed out that there were multiple businesses at one address.  I was originally grouping all the long/lat's together like this and putting a title saying "Multiple businesses at this location..." but they thought the user base would be confused by it and as google clusters around a point thats what they want.

Comment: I'm also using MarkerClusterer as well to show less markers at zoomed-out levels.